# How do you loop through view id's?

Tags: android

For my android app I need to make an array of `View` ID's.

The array will hold 81 values so it's quite lengthy to add them one by one.
This is how it looks now:

```
cells[0] = R.id.Square00;
cells[1] = R.id.Square01;
cells[2] = R.id.Square02;
cells[3] = R.id.Square03;
cells[4] = R.id.Square04;
cells[5] = R.id.Square05;
//All the way to 80.
```

Is there a shorter/more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: So many ways.. You can use `setId()` and `getId()` dynamically in your code or there is `getIndentifier()` method from **Resources** class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thankfully, there is. Use [`getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
Resources r = getResources();
String name = getPackageName();
int[] cells = new int[81];
for(int i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
    if(i < 10)
        cells[i] = r.getIdentifier("Squares0" + i, "id", name);
    else
        cells[i] = r.getIdentifier("Squares" + i, "id", name);
}
```

Comment: I'd call getPackageName() once prior looping

Answer (score 1):

> Sam's answer is better but i think i should share an alternative

```
int [] ids = new int [] {R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2, ...};
Button [] arrayButton = new Button[ids.length];

for(int i=0 ; i < arrayButton.length ; i++)
{
  arrayButton[i] = (Button) findViewById(ids[i]);
}
```

**Modified form of Sam Answer**

No need of if else use Integer String Formating

```
Resources r = getResources();
String name = getPackageName();

int[] resIDs = new int[81];

for(int i = 0; i < 81; i++) 
{
        resIDs[i] = r.getIdentifier("Squares0" + String.format("%03d", i), "id", name);
}
```